# Why font added to Wordpress plugin folder are not available in Wordpress after plugin installation?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

[image]

`incons.woff` is added to the assets folder. Then plugin version get commited with SVN, but when I refere in `Additional CSS` to the file, it is not applied. Why?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Icons';
    src: url(/wp-content/plugins/tikex/assets/icons.woff);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

---

I also tried bundle css to the shortcode in the php file:

```
wp_register_style( $this->plugin_slug . '-shortcode-style36', plugins_url( 'assets/css/ShortCode36.css', dirname( __FILE__ ) ), $this->version );
```

and refere in css to the font:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Icons';
    src: url(../icons.woff);
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Without any luck.

Comment: `plugins_loaded` fires before `setup_theme` (@See [Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)). If you're not getting a 404 on the requested url, I would suggest it's a loading priority conflict. eg: The plugin's stylesheet loading before the theme stylesheet which is overwriting it.

Comment: I get 404: `GET https://borespiac.hu/wp-content/plugins/tikex/assets/icons.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 404` What does it mean?

Comment: Are you loading it from style.css ? The default theme's stylesheet ? Or from the plugin stylesheet ?

Comment: Now I try to load from both, if style from default theme style sheet is removed, then it does not raise the 404, why? But also does not show the icon.